# Convert numbers (1-1000) to words in console log using Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, converters

So I was able to convert #1 - 9 into words using Javascript in console log. 
How can I get my code to show the remaining numbers, which would be 10-1000?

```
function numbersToWords(value) {
        let input = String(value).split('');
        let mapData = {
            "0": "Zero",
            "1": "One",
            "2": "Two",
            "3": "Three",
            "4": "Four",
            "5": "Five",
            "6": "Six",
            "7": "Seven",
            "8": "Eight",
            "9": "Nine",
        };

        let output = '';
        var tempArray = []
        for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            tempArray.push(mapData[input[i]])
        }
        output = tempArray.join(' ');
        return output;
    }

    console.log(numbersToWords(123456789));
```

Comment: Write the remaining mappings between number and word...?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that without separator or array instead of string.

```
// value = '1/2/23/16'
let input = String(value).split('/');
//or
// value = ['12', '34']
```